# Views title instead of id

Tags: views, 8

I have create new view showing all content referenced by given tag using contextual filter `(field_tag: Content) Content: ID zawartości`. Now I struggle how to overwrite the view page title with id of tag instead of node id provided as argument of contextual title.

[image]

In the contextual filters menu I have only following tokens avaliable:

[image]

while I am looking for the token allowing me to use "tag title" instead of "tag id" in the view page title.

The general idea is to have a page listing all content which is referenced by a tag given as a url argument.

I have read answers for similar questions here, but can't really find working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I benefited from both @No Sssweat and @Neograph734 answers.

First of all I added `(field_tag: Content) Content: Title [nie pokazuj]` field. Than I entered `Content: Title` field marked "modify output value" and get replacement token from there.

At the end I inputed the replacement token in contextual filter menu.

As @Neograph734 mentioned my problem was that the contextual filter did not proper list all available tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Add (field_tag: Content) Content: ID to your fields.

You must **move field_tag above the title**, so the field_tag token becomes available.

Then click on the title field and re-write the results. click on Available tokens, and you should see the field_tag token which you then copy and paste it on the rewrite box.

**If you are re-writing the link**, make sure you **unchecked** the `Link this field to the original piece of content` box, other wise your re-write won't apply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to overwrite "page view title" and not the "Content: Title" field. Even If I have the fields rearranged no additional token is displayed in "Avaliable tokens" while I click on "Contextual Filters" (where I may "overwrite title").

Comment: oh, I over looked your drupal 8 tag.

Comment: The contextual filter does not proper list all available tokens, but in most cases it does work with fields tokens also. (At least with D7).